# How to enable/disable GPS location services on Android 9 via ADB commands (not rooted device)

Tags: android, automation, gps, adb

I'm doing automation for Android and for some tests I need to disable/enable location services from code. 
I tried such commands:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed -gps
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0
```

but nothing seems to be working on Android 7...9.

Is there any way to do that in one command?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Enable:
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 3

Disable:
adb shell settings put secure location_mode 0